# trying to connect Microsoft dynamics crm by web api in java

Tags: java, dynamics-crm

I am trying to connect Microsoft dynamics crm by web api in java

```
private final static String AUTHORITY = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
private final static String CLIENT_ID = "XXXXXXXXXXXX";
private final static String RESOURCE = "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {

    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
            System.in))) {
        System.out.print("Enter username: ");
        String username = br.readLine();
        System.out.print("Enter password: ");
        String password = br.readLine();

        AuthenticationResult result = getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials(
                username, password);
        System.out.println("Access Token - " + result.getAccessToken());
        System.out.println("Refresh Token - " + result.getRefreshToken());
        System.out.println("ID Token - " + result.getIdToken());
    }
}

private static AuthenticationResult getAccessTokenFromUserCredentials(
        String username, String password) throws Exception {
    AuthenticationContext context = null;
    AuthenticationResult result = null;
    ExecutorService service = null;
    try {
        service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);
        context = new AuthenticationContext(AUTHORITY, false, service);
        Future<AuthenticationResult> future = context.acquireToken(
                RESOURCE, CLIENT_ID, username, password, null);
        result = future.get();
    } finally {
        service.shutdown();
    }

    if (result == null) {
        throw new ServiceUnavailableException(
                "authentication result was null");
    }
    return result;
}
```

}

I have a Ms dynamics account ,but I dont know how to get the AUTHORITY , CLIENT_ID and RESOURCE.

I tried by creating my app in https://portal.azure.com there I can see the application_id. is that the clientid I have to use.

Can anyone please tell me how can I get these Crendentials.

Thanks in Advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Client Id = Application Id

Resource = CRM Url

Authority = OAUTH 2.0 AUTHORIZATION ENDPOINT - found under Endpoints at the top of the App Registrations list